# Can't seem to get my comboBox to select anything

Tags: c#, combobox

I am using datareader to read data from my Database and store them to a string. But I can't seem the use the data that was stored on the string to do anything to my comboBox like what I wanted it to do on my if statements.

I Have a comboBox Selected Index statement which is working fine.

```
if (cboBase.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                cboTeam.Items.Clear();
                cboTeam.Items.Add("1");
                cboTeam.Items.Add("2");
                cboTeam.Items.Add("3");
                cboTeam.Items.Add("4");
                cboTeam.Items.Add("6");
                cboTeam.Items.Add("8");
                cboTeam.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }
            else if (cboBase.SelectedIndex == 1)
            {
                cboTeam.Items.Clear();
                cboTeam.Items.Add("5");
                cboTeam.Items.Add("7");
                cboTeam.Items.Add("9");
                cboTeam.Items.Add("10");
                cboTeam.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                cboTeam.Items.Clear();
                cboTeam.Items.Add("11");
                cboTeam.Items.Add("12");
                cboTeam.Items.Add("13");
                cboTeam.Items.Add("14");
                cboTeam.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }
```

When I used my datareader's data to select cboBase everything is working fine. But when I tried the same method to select the cboTeam and perform click on the radioButton, it's not working... Can someone guide me on the right path?

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring);
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT EmployeeID, HomeBase, TeamID, StaffType, PIC From Employee WHERE EmployeeID ='" + txtEmployeeID.Text + "'", con);
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                string EmployeeID = null;
                string HomeBase = null;
                string TeamID = null;
                string Position = null;
                string PIC = null;
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    EmployeeID = reader.GetInt32(0).ToString();
                    HomeBase = reader.GetString(1).ToString();
                    TeamID = reader.GetInt32(2).ToString();
                    Position = reader.GetInt32(3).ToString();
                    PIC = reader.GetInt32(4).ToString();

                }
                if (HomeBase == "JUR")
                {
                    cboBase.SelectedIndex = 0;
                }
                else if (HomeBase == "LVR")
                {
                    cboBase.SelectedIndex = 1;
                }
                else if (HomeBase == "SBW")
                {
                    cboBase.SelectedIndex = 2;
                }
                else if (TeamID == "1")
                {
                    cboTeam.SelectedIndex = 0;
                }
                else if (TeamID == "2")
                {
                    cboTeam.SelectedIndex = 1;
                }
                else if (TeamID == "3")
                {
                    cboTeam.SelectedIndex = 2;
                }
                else if (TeamID == "4")
                {
                    cboTeam.SelectedIndex = 3;
                }
                else if (TeamID == "6")
                {
                    cboTeam.SelectedIndex = 4;
                }
                else if (TeamID == "8")
                {
                    cboTeam.SelectedIndex = 5;
                }
                else if (TeamID == "5")
                {
                    cboTeam.SelectedIndex = 0;
                }
                else if (TeamID == "7")
                {
                    cboTeam.SelectedIndex = 1;
                }
                else if (TeamID == "8")
                {
                    cboTeam.SelectedIndex = 2;
                }
                else if (TeamID == "10")
                {
                    cboTeam.SelectedIndex = 3;
                }
                else if (TeamID == "11")
                {
                    cboTeam.SelectedIndex = 0;
                }
                else if (TeamID == "12")
                {
                    cboTeam.SelectedIndex = 1;
                }
                else if (TeamID == "13")
                {
                    cboTeam.SelectedIndex = 2;
                }
                else if (TeamID == "14")
                {
                    cboTeam.SelectedIndex = 3;
                }
                else if (Position == "1")
                {
                    cboPosition.SelectedIndex = 0;
                }
                else if (Position == "2")
                {
                    cboPosition.SelectedIndex = 1;
                }
                else if (Position == "3")
                {
                    cboPosition.SelectedIndex = 2;
                }
                else if (PIC == "1")
                {
                    radioPIC.PerformClick();
                }
                else if (PIC == "0")
                {
                    radioNo.PerformClick();
                }
```

Comment: Looks like you did not try to debug the code and understand the logic of the code.You have incorrect `if-else-if` structure. As per your code once an item in `cboBase` is selected none of the `else if` will be executed. So what you need to do is to have start different `if-else-if` for selecting Item in `cboTeam` and another one for `dboPosition`.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Thank you! I get what you meant after I saw this comment. Thanks for guiding me back to the right path... Was probably too tired yesterday night. Thanks!